# How to setup Maven dependencies between test folders in two projects?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a project setup like this:

```
parent
     |_____project-a
     |_____project-b
```

I want classes in the **test** folder of project-b to resolve classes in the test folder of project-a.

Actually, I want to access both classes from the main folder and stuff from the test folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-138

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build project A with the goal test-jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>               
        </plugin>
```

Then include it with type `test-jar` in project B:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since content of test folder is not included into target for project it cannot be used outside.
The best way i think is to move common classes to project like 'project-testcommons' and use it in project-a and project-b with 'test' scope.

Comment: For larger projects, this makes more sense than the `test-jar` solution I provided - dependency management will be handled correctly